# C++ online Role Playing Game (RPG)

Tags: c++, directx

So I've been learning C++ and SDL to make some basic 2d games. I want to create a game sort of like World of Warcraft but a 2D version. I want it to be on-line and use a database or something to start data like amount of Gold, HP, etc. I was wondering though, if I do this in SDL, would it still work on-line or would the user have to download SDL themselves to play?

I just want a game like this but be able to play it with some friends, just for learning purposes you know. I was also looking at DirectX because everyone has that on windows pretty much. Anyways much help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: nitpick: "RPG" stands for "Role Playing Game", so you're saying "C++ online [role-playing game game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome)"; please stop.

Comment: 1) I suggest using SDL.NET with C# or VB.NET 2) Don't make it online. Online takes 4x the amount of work so decide between making it online or making it 4x better as single (or multiple) player (with multiple joypads on one machine and not over lan if multi player)

Comment: A role-playing game that's single player/offline? That kinda defeats the purpose. About as useful as an offline VOIP application.

Comment: @MSalters: It seems you never enjoyed Ultima, Wizardry, Might and Magic etc. :-)

Comment: @Frerich: you're right. I did play some of those, but indeed never enjoyed them. WoW makes much more sense as an RPG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No offense, but an RPG is definately the last thing a new programmer should attempt to create.  They are the most time, resource, and skill intensive style of game one could possibly try to create.  I speak from experience here and can say that RPGs are huge time sinks, even for experienced game studios.  At best, you might get a basic map working before you run out of time and patience.

If you want a game you can play with your friends, why not multiplayer tic-tac-toe or even artillery or something similiar.  You'll have more success and may actually have something to show your friends when you are done.

Comment: Though not a direct answer, you are right.  I make rpg's in my spare time and I have *never* finished one.  Ever, and the programming is the easiest part for me.

Comment: -1: *Everybody* should create a RPG game. And an IRC client. And so on. A new programmer should try these things since he's motivated to do so and he's familiar with the problem domain. It doesn't matter too much whether the project ends as intended - the journey is the reward. :-)

Comment: @Frerich: yes and no. A project you never complete is a lot less valuable as a learning exercise than one you *do* complete. If you haven't completed it, you're unable to tell if the lessons you learned from it were actually the right ones. On the other hand, you're absolutely right that a programmer should focus on projects he's motivated to do if he wants to learn.

Comment: As @Michael says, though, RPG's aren't very interesting from a programming point of view. If the goal is to get better at programming, most other types of games would be more productive. A RPG generally consists of fairly simple programming, and *a lot* of time "wasted" (as in, they won't make you a better programmer) on other tasks, such as writing dialogue, creating art assets and so on. If the goal is to get better at programming, it might be better to focus on a type of game that emphasize game mechanics (which are code) more than story (which is not)

Comment: @Frerich: Perhaps everyone, eventually, should try one.  Not as a beginner project and definately not an MMRPG.  Learning to scope is one of the most fundamental things a professional game programmer must learn and relearn.   A MMRPG/RPG is beyond the scope of most small game companies, let alone a single, beginner hobbiest.  While there are lessons to be learned in the attempt (and it will only be an attempt), they are lessons best left for later on.  Honestly, the biggest lesson that will be learned here is that making games is frustrating, slow, and asset intensive.  Leave that for later!

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need to include SDL's runtime library for the game to run on other computers. This will apply no matter what library you use.

Answer (score 2):

For the game itself some libraries are installed in Windows, but in order to achieve other functionality (online gameplay, gampad, etc)you must tell the user to install the other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you use SDL, you would be using it for a local graphical client that the user would either download or install. For that, you don't need to have the user download the SDL library  separateoly – you can simply put the SDL runtime DLL in the same directory as your executable and package both into the client installer. Of course, you must abide by the GNU LGPL requirements if you do this; the SDL website has details.

As far as the online piece, I'm not sure what you have in mind. I'm guessing either you'll have clients talking directly to each other in some sort of peer-to-peer fashion, or you'll have an back-end server run by you that handles the common game mechanics. I don't think you'll find SDL of much help in either case. But if you go with the back-end server, you can use whatever libraries you like for that server without impact on the user, since the user will only ever deal with the client.

Answer (score 1):

For flat 2D, probably the easiest approach is to use a web interface not SDL. Web browsers are common on Macs and Linux, too, and you might even be able to support smartphones.

Still, you would have to learn how to split work between the clients and the central server. This is not always trivial. Obviously, stuff like # of gold coins would be on the server. Keyboard input is accepted first on the client. But the direction in which your toon is looking? Should the server know that?